# Dynamically change color of polygon in linked KML file

Tags: javascript, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am looking to create a Choropleth map made up of polygons overlaid atop Google Earth via the plug-in using JavaScript.

The polygons exist in a KML file, all with unique IDs, on a server (not necessarily mine).
I want to be able to change the color of the polygon dynamically to show different data sets.

Is this doable?

I looked up the  KML mechanism, but that only works with files on the same server.

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load/parse remote KML via the [Google Earth API](https://developers.google.com/earth/) from any network accessible URL (same server or otherwise) then iterate over the KML objects and programmatically change the styles and the polygon colors.

```
var href = 'http://code.google.com/'
           + 'apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example.kml';

google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {
      if (kmlObject) {
         checkObject(kmlObject);
         // append KML objects to current view
         ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
      }    
});

function checkObject(kmlObject) {
    var type = kmlObject.getType();         
    if (type == 'KmlDocument' || type == 'KmlFolder') {
        var features = kmlObject.getFeatures();
        if (features.hasChildNodes()) {
            var children = features.getChildNodes();                    
            for (i=0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                checkObject(children.item(i));                      
            }
        }
    } else if (type == 'KmlPlacemark') {
        // check/set style, change color, etc.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/kml#fetchkml_and_parsekml